# how to insert checkbox data into database codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just want to ask if how can I save only 1 checkbox if they have the same name given .

for example I have this checkbox and only one of them needs to save on my table

```
<input type="checkbox" name="loan" value="First Loan Application"> First Loan Application
<input type="checkbox" name="loan" value="Renewal"> Renewal
```

and on my table I have a field that is called `loan`

can I do just like this on my `controller`

```
function insert_data(){
   $data = array(
     'loan' => $this->input->post('loan'),
      ....
   );
}
```

and on my view I have this

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/insert_data">

<input type="checkbox" name="loan" value="First Loan Application"> First Loan Application
<input type="checkbox" name="loan" value="Renewal"> Renewal

</form>
```

Could someone help me if I am doing it correctly or I am missing something.

Comment: use radio button which will fulfill your need

Comment: you need a `radio button` or `select box` instead of check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M.Hemant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966773/how-to-insert-checkbox-data-into-database-codeigniter-framework#comment102344246_57966773) said, you should use radio button, so users can choose only one of them.

Beside, you should design your database with `tinyint` type for that column. For example, store `0` for `First Loan Application`, `1` for `Renewal`.
Then, the database will use less space than varchar type, and easier indexing.

```
<input type="radio" name="loan" value="0"> First Loan Application
<input type="radio" name="loan" value="1"> Renewal
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to use radio buttons when you want user to select only one choice but if you want to give checkboxes for multiple selection, here is an easy approach for this. In your html for input type checkbox change name attribute to an array like this.

```
 <form method='post'>
<input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value='1'/>1
 <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value='2'/>2
  <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value='3'/>3
  <button type='submit' name='sub'>sub</button>
  </form>
```

Now in the php part of your file check for this test array using isset function

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub'])){
    print_r($_REQUEST['test']);
}
```

Here when print_r statement is executed you can see the value that are checked in checkboxes.Now you can use implode function that will convert the array into the string which can be stored in database in a single column